# How to handle duplicate column(s) in table definition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Given a dataframe with following schema . The problem is that the dataframe is dynamic and so is its field . So you can pre assume a given schema.

```
root
 |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |-- c: long (nullable = true)
 |-- d: long (nullable = true)
 |-- a: long (nullable = true)
```

The following error is shown :-

```
Found duplicate column(s) in table definition
```

how should we rename the column name to remove ambiguity

Comment: you can simply use toDF after reading dataframe and pass explicit column names.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can rename it

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("a", 1, "a"),
  ("a", 1, "a"),
  ("a", 1, "a")
).toDF("a", "x", "a")

val columns = List("a", "b", "c")
val newDF = df.toDF(columns: _*)

newDF.show(false)
newDF.printSchema()
```

New Output:

```
+---+---+---+
|a  |b  |c  |
+---+---+---+
|a  |1  |a  |
|a  |1  |a  |
|a  |1  |a  |
+---+---+---+
```

New Schema:

```
root
 |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |-- b: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- c: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: The same works with python: `df.toDF(*["a", "b", "c"])`

Comment: The problem is that the dataframe is dynamic and so is its field . So you can pre assume a given schema.